# Sony Vaio Inverter

Tags: inverter

My sony vaio vpcee3j1e laptop backlight doesn't work.Because the inverter is not working anymore. Since I have some urgent code to write, I need to fix it.I do not have any tools to make measures so i am trying to guess what could be the fault. The capacitors seems ok,but there is a component I haven't seen before and it's the only one who present some trace of burned.The body of this component is made of ferromagnetic and is wired to the circuit using 3 connection. Have a look:
[image: vaio vpcee3j1e inverter]

On the circuit board the ref is: *CK 66 394V-0*

Does anyone know what is this component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that component is a piezoelectric transformer.
Most laptop and LCD screens have CCFL tube backlights.
As far as I know, the only efficient ways to generate the several hundred volts required to drive CCFL tubes -- when all you have is battery power -- involves either a piezoelectric transformer or a copper-wire transformer, or both.

(FIXME: add images of backlight inverters with piezoelectric transformers from

http://www.nec-tokin.com/english/product/piezodevice2/piezo_inverter.html

http://www.ceratech.co.jp/english/product_e/01_04_02.html

http://www.mmech.com/~mmechc5/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=66&Itemid=98

http://www.mmech.com/transformers

)

I see that the entire screen (including the entire backlight inverter board with the transformers already installed on it) is available from many sources, a few of which also offer repair services.
[(a)](http://www.nerdstech.co.uk/sony-vaio-vpcee3j1ewi-laptop-screen-repair.htm) [(b)](http://www.alibaba.com/for-sony-vaio-laptop-lcd-screens-suppliers.html) [(c)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009P7LATO) [(d)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA2720X23653) [(e)](http://www.aceqtech.com/sony-vaio-vpcee3j1ewi-laptop-lcd-screen-156-wxga-hd-led.html) [(f)](http://www.replacedirect.nl/category/198170-222566/sony-vaio-vpc-ee3j1e-laptop-backlight-inverter-vervangen.html?prrel=7220088)

However, I've seen at least [one person](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZYLk-DtDNM) have a "backlight won't turn on" problem that was fixed by replacing a fuse on the motherboard.

Comment: Not to mention it will almost certainly be a custom manufactured part for Sony. It won't be available from components suppliers such as Digikey, Farnell, Mouser etc... Regrettably you may have to contact a Sony service center for the part if indeed it is responsible for the failure.

Comment: I finally manage to get an instrument and measure the output of the inverter. It turns out that it is perfectly working but the solder of the connection with the CCFL's anode was the actual problem:it was almost completely melted and the wire was burned but still slightly attached. Replacing the wire and the solder at the anode solved the problem. Thanks for the infos about the piezoelectric transformer. I studied transformers in the first semester (EE) but with no mention of that kind of transformer.